# percentage of values matching between two columns of a csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"true_key" :["Astral","Blob","Blob","Cat","Astral"], "true_key2": ["Japan","Astral","Blob","quics","Cat"]})
```

How do I calculate the percentage of values present in true_key that are present in true_key2
and vice versa?

> So, as we can see 100% of true_key values are present in true_key2. And 60% of
> true_key2 are present in true_key

Is there any other method to do it in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny My apologies, edited! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use set intersection and divide len accordingly:

```
mutual_len = len(set(df['true_key']).intersection(set(df['true_key2'])))
mutual_len / df['true_key'].nunique(), mutual_len / df['true_key2'].nunique()
```

(1.0, 0.6)

Comment: It looks good to me! I'll wait for a while, otherwise I'll accept this. Do you think the complexity would be a lot if I try to run this on a dataframe comparing 1 column with 70 columns and 150k rows?

Comment: would guess it's not a problem